# What does "#queue" mean in (def empty-queue #queue [])?

Tags: function, clojure, clojurescript, re-frame

Reading re-frame's source code, I stumbled upon [this line](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/cee6d27373233ed3633c886adb321d402b67afd7/src/re_frame/interop.cljs#L8):

```
(def empty-queue #queue [])
```

What is `#queue`? What effect does it have?

Comment: I think it might be a reader tag, but not sure what is it in there for? Never used those tags myself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#queue []` is a [tagged literal](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_tagged_literals): `#queue` uses the `queue` member of `*data-readers*` to transform or interpret `[]`.

The specific definition of this reader in [src/main/clojure/cljs/tagged_literals.cljs](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/aa5f001300e9aebd976cb180f5b7ccb37fcb6898/src/main/clojure/cljs/tagged_literals.cljc#L13) in the ClojureScript repository, referenced from the [`*cljs-data-readers*` definition below](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/aa5f001300e9aebd976cb180f5b7ccb37fcb6898/src/main/clojure/cljs/tagged_literals.cljc#L87); it transforms `[]` from a vector into a [cljs.core.PersistentQueue](https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/PersistentQueue).

See also the documentation at https://cljs.github.io/api/syntax/queue-literal

---

The persistent queue structures in both Clojure and ClojureScript exist to allow efficient pushing onto one end and popping from the other -- as opposed to lists and vectors, which are only efficient when pushing and popping from the same side.

Comment: Why would I use such tagged literal instead of simply using `cljs.core.PersistentQueue.EMPTY` directly?

Comment: Terseness? It very much is syntactic sugar.

Comment: I see. Thanks, that explains it!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It also makes sense for something like EDN or cljc, where a different language than cljs might have a queue structure but would of course not have cljs.core.PersistentQueue. A clj-jvm project could define a reader tag for #queue that uses clojure.core.PersistentQueue.

Comment: @amalloy So that could be considered a syntactic sugar as well, as I could still do `#?(:clj ... :cljs ...)` to get the desired queue type in both .clj and .cljs. EDN use case is more interesting though.